# Using accessor mutator with a belongsTo relationship

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, mutators

Using Laravel 4 and I have a mutator set up in my User model:

```
public function getFullnameAttribute($value)
{
    return $this->first_name. ' ' .$this->last_name;
}
```

But I have a relationship set up in my Cars model for a user ID linked to that car:

```
public function salesManager()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('User', 'sales_manager')->select('first_name', 'last_name');
}
```

I am calling that relationship on my Car table:

```
$cars = Car::with('marqueBasic', 'modelBasic', 'salesManager')
    ->get();
```

Now, how can I do e.g.

```
$car->salesManager->fullname
```

Currently doesn't work, which I am assuming because its in another model to the one thats being called?

The error is: "Trying to get property of non-object"

Am I calling the mutator in the wrong place? I have tried putting it into the relationship select fields but also searched for a field name of fullname and errors out.

Comment: What do you mean by "doesn't work"? Are you getting an error? Are you getting empty value when you access ->fullname? Anything else happens?

Comment: "Trying to get property of non-object" - Question edited.

Comment: It measn one of your cars does not have "sales_manager" set, hence when you don $car->salesManager->fullname you're trying to get ->fullname from a null value

Comment: Or there might be one other reason :) please make sure that you have relation set for all cars, while I post the answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The probable reason is that you are defining a list of fields to be fetched for the relation.

In order to understand why, you need to first understand how Eloquent eagerly loads **salesManager** relation when you ask it to fetch **all Cars with their SalesManager**. Eloquent does the following in such situation:

1. Load all cars
2. Get values of **sales_manager** columns for all loaded cars
3. Load all users that have id within the values from point 2.
4. Map loaded user models to cars by matchingg id of fetched user model and car's sales_manager column.

As you can see, step 4 is impossible to do. User's **id** field is not listed in the list of fields to be fetched for **salesManager** relation so Eloquent, when eagerly loading **salesManager**, won't have a way to match fetched users with the cars. You need to add the field you're referencing in your **salesManager** relation to the list:

```
public function salesManager()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('User', 'sales_manager')->select('first_name', 'last_name', 'id');
}
```