# Mutator and relations

Tags: laravel, orm, laravel-5, model

Using Laravel 5.2, I have a mutator set up in my Team model:

```
public function getNameAttribute($value)
{
    if ($this->exists) {
        return !empty($value) ? $value : $this->organization()->first()->name;
    }
    return null;
}
```

Relation with Organization's model:

```
public function organization()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Models\Organization')->withTimestamps();
}
```

when `$team->name` is empty, I try to get `$this->organization()->first()->name` but.. an error occurred :

> Trying to get property of non-object

After two hours, I haven't found the problem

EDIT:

```
Schema::table('organization_team', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->foreign('organization_id')
                ->references('id')
                ->on('organizations')
                ->onUpdate('cascade')
                ->onDelete('cascade');

            $table->foreign('team_id')
                ->references('id')
                ->on('teams')
                ->onUpdate('cascade')
                ->onDelete('cascade');
        });
```

Comment: I have found an other topic. I think that i have the same problem. [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31696669/using-accessor-mutator-with-a-belongsto-relationship) but i don't understood how he resolves the problem.

Answer (score 1):

It's very simple, just do it like that:

```
 public function getNameAttribute($value)
    {
        if ($this->exists) {
            return !empty($value) ? $value : $this->organization
                                                   ->first()->name;
        }
        return null;
    }
```

Comment: Would you provide the complete error message? which line is throwing that error?

Comment: [link](http://image.noelshack.com/fichiers/2016/34/1471849440-error.png)

Comment: Which line is 41 in Team.php?

Comment: are you sure this team has an organisation related to it?

Comment: Yes sure, i have edit my first post. But when i do a var_dump on `$this->organisation->first()->name` , i have the value what i want, but when i try to get `$team->name`, an error occurred. it's really strange.

Comment: OK that makes a lot of sense. Because how Laravel works. It will try first to get the value of $team->name then runs the mutator on it. I will try something then update my answer.

Comment: One moment, is there really a $team object. Or the object itself might be null?

Comment: I have found the problem, it s my bad. `return $this->organizations->first() ? $this->organizations->first()->name : $value;` It's better to check if the relation exists. When i went display result, one team doesn't have organization, so when i went the name, the error was founded

Answer (score 0):

`$this->organization()->first()`  must return a null in your application.

So check your database and add some relation data.

You can find a org name like this.

```
$this->organization->first(function ($item) {
    return ! empty($item->name);
})->name;
```

Comment: When i make a dd() on this, i have a good result but without, still same error.